# How to make a preloader hide the scroll bar?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I made a preloader but when playing it, scrollbars are visible. How to remove them? JS has `display: none;` because preloader is set to `display: flex;`

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
  $('.preloader').delay(500).fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $(this).attr('style', 'display: none !important');
  });
});
```

```css
.preloader {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 10002;
  background-color: #fefefe;
}
```

```html
<div class="preloader d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
  <div class="spinner-border text-danger" style="width: 10rem; height: 
             10rem;" role="status">
    <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no scrollbar in your setup. Do you mean the default scrollbar which appears when the content is larger as the viewport of your browser window?

If yes, set the overflow of your body element to hidden. And add an jquery line which change the overflow to auto when the side is loaded.

```
#css
body {
  overflow:hidden;
} 
#js 
 $(window).on('load', function(){
        $('.preloader').delay(500).fadeOut('slow', function(){
            $(this).attr('style', 'display: none !important');
            /// Ad this line below
            $('body').css("overflow","auto");
        });       
    });
```

https://codepen.io/Cleee/pen/eYOBNPy

Comment: You helped me.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Add position as absolute

.preloader { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; z-index: 10002; background-color: #fefefe; }

and try. That must fix the issue